# React Native unable to resolve module @react-native/assets/registry

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I’ve been facing a weird error in my react native (v0.68.2) project for a week now I would really appreciate any help its been driving me crazy.

For some reason, the assets folder inside the @react-native folder in node_modules seems to get deleted on its own causing this error:

`Error: unable to resolve module @react-native/assets/registry from /Users/xx/ApplicationPath/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource.js: @react-native/assets/registry could not be found within the project or in these directories:`

From what I can tell when I delete the node_modules folder and run `yarn` or `npm install` the assets folder is installed correctly within @react-native but after some time it randomly gets deleted and I have no idea why. A similar thing happens in the @react-navigation/elements/src folder the assets folder also gets deleted.

After deleting node_modules and running yarn
[image]

A few moments later

[image]

Answer (score 5):

check your metro.config.js

for newer react native version

```
const path = require("path");
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require("@react-native/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts } } = defaultConfig;

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
  },
  watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../")],
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);
```

it should be something like this
then reset cache by npm start --reset-cache

it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen and figured out that I had a file `.yarnclean` that was removing `assets/` folder and a bunch of other 'unneccesary' things. Check if that exists.

Comment: I just ended up creating a new project and it stopped but i think that might have been the problem

Answer (score 1):

I've had that same problem. In my case I just restarted expo and refreshed the simulator and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountered same problome after add metro.config.js and npm install.
So i delete metro.config.js and all of files in node_modules folder.
After run npm install.

And i delete Expo Go app cache files in my device.
My device is android device.
If you same my environment, Go to Settings > Apps > Expo Go > Storage & cache.
And click 'Clear storage' or 'Clear cache'.

And reconnect your development application.